# How to send jQuery Autocomplete categories as part of the form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have jquery autocomplete with categories, when a person clicks on it with the mouse it gets send to a php page with that value and reports back a page. This works just fine.

However i want the category to be send with it.

Here is the inital part..

```
    $( "#tipapp" ).catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: data,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $("input#tipapp").val(ui.item.label);
                $("#tipapp").submit();
            },
    }).data("catcomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>").data("item.catcomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
    };
```

And the feed to the php:

```
    $("#tipapp").submit(function() {
        $('#output').load('resultapp.php', {value: $(this).val()}); 
    });
```

From what i read, i thought i could simply add to the php line something like:

```
$('#output').load('resultapp.php', {value: $(this).val(), cat: item.category});
```

But no luck, i changed then also

```
select: function(event, ui, item) {
$("input#tipapp").cat(ui.item.category);
```

Ofcourse, no luck. There are tons of pages working with autocomplete and forms and such, but this is specific for the categories.

Am i missing something simple here? I could just do a find on the item to get the category in the php file i am calling, but if its a simple fix then it would save some code and a extra call to the database.

Comment: So you want to filter by word based on a current category?

Comment: No, i just want the "category" to be send towards the php file too. That way i can just read it out as $_POST['cat']

Comment: Well according to this http://jsfiddle.net/VJ4ap/ - and by using fiddler to intercept the request, it looks like load is sending `value=value&cat=category` as the body of the request to resultapp.php

Comment: This works: value: "value", cat: "category" there is nothing wrong with that. The problem is how to get the category value from the selected item in there.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood what you were asking! - Is the category a select list? if so you should just be able to do `$("#seleclistid option:selected").val()`

Comment: I tried adding `$("input#tipapp option:selected").val()` and similar variations. But no luck, i've got the print_r($_POST) showing me only 1 value.

Comment: Would you like to make a jsfiddle with the code in question?

Comment: Well it fetches data from a php again, so i dont know how i can "fake" that. I could put down partial part?

Comment: Yeah - just an piece of exemplar HTML + JS is fine. Might want to look at Boaz's answer first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ui.item.category` should indeed contain the item's category value. The problem is that the `ui` object is probably undefined in the scope of the ultimate `submit()` handler.

To overcome this, you can store the category value in the input element's data, before calling the handler, like so:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    $("input#tipapp").val(ui.item.label).data('category',ui.item.category);
    $("#tipapp").submit();
}
```

Then in the handler, you can retrieve the category value from the input element's data, like so:

```
$("#tipapp").submit(function() {
    $('#output').load('resultapp.php', {value: $(this).val(), cat:$(this).data('category')}); 
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. I was close but no cigar for me.